# "...ambiguous in the namespace..." errors when compiling VB.NET code

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm getting a ton of errors like this when attempting to build an empty VB.NET project:

'GenerateCodeAttribute' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.CodeDom.Compiler'

Is this some problem with my .NET installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked your references that you're not linked to multiple copies of core libs ?

If you've recently converted, this can happen.

Looks like this guy had the same issue:

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/161172.aspx

Comment: This helped me solve a similar issue. I had imported both C# and VB versions of a library.